# Should you import types for firebase from 'firebase' or 'firebase/app'?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am using firebase in an Angular-typescript application.

Often I need to import types from firebase, and I don't know if I should import like this:

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
```

or

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase';
```

If you have the knowledge, I would also very much like to hear the difference (if any) between the 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should import from `firebase/app` as that is the primary entry point for Firebase and is tree shakable.